# Dynamic Dialog Containing Linear Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am trying to make a dialog that consists of a LinearLayout which contains a number of other `LinearLayout`s that are effectively `Button`s that each bring you to a website. Instead of statically making each `LinearLayout` `Button` in the layout xml file, I have a JSON feed that has a possibly changing number of buttons to display in the dialog. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098314/dynamically-add-buttons-to-dialog) that looks similar...

... but I'm not sure how to dynamically add `LinearLayouts` to a `Dialog`. The data for each of the `LinearLayout` buttons gets parsed into an ArrayList of items, each representing a `Button` in the `Dialog`.

Comment: And why you trying to use LinearLayouts instead of using a relativeLayout?

Comment: I figure it would be less messy to just use "addView()" to add each "button" to the containing LinearLayout, whereas otherwise I would have to make each "button" relative to the one created before it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should use a RelativeLayout for this:

To notice, where your last created button is and to set the next one to the next position costs not so much performance as creating new layouts. You should try to call addView(); as less as possible, because each time the view must be rendered again.

But if it's necessary to add LinearLayouts, here is a sample code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
viewGroup.addView(linearLayout);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am a little confused about how the ViewGroup is used. How do I set viewGroup and why is a ViewGroup used?

Comment: All layouts are extending from the ViewGroup. A ViewGroup just describe, that the view could have children. So you could cast your LinearLayout to a ViewGroup. -> Use a DialogFragment and inflate a XML, which just has a LinearLayout in it. Give the LinearLayout an id. After inflate get the Layout from the XML by "findViewById". This will be your "viewGroup", where you can add all your other LinearLayouts... But take a look on invariant's answer below. It's much better, instead of using addView :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` and control it with an adapter.
For the dialog you can use a `DialogFragment`. Override the `onCreateDialog` method and return an `AlertDialog` inside. The `AlertDialog.Builder` has the `setView` method that you can use to inflate your list or recycler. Then just keep a reference to the adapter in your dialog fragment and use it to load your layout-buttons dynamically.

For example:

```
public class WebsitePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

Adapter adapter = new YourRecyclerViewAdapter();

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final RecyclerView contentView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(...
    contentView.setAdapter(adapter);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(contentView);
    return builder.create();
    }
}
```

If you don't want scrolling behavior, you can still use this pattern with any adapter view, like the https://github.com/frankiesardo/LinearListView lib that uses `LinearLayout` like a `ListView`.

Comment: I will give this a try, but is there any insight you can give as to what's happening in the Adapter?

Comment: @Ben check out this example: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-recyclerview-example#25-creating-recyclerview-adapter
The adapter should hold the data (for example a list of website URIs) so it can create a view per URI and put it in the recycler view. This is a very common pattern and you can find tons of examples for it. With this approach, the adapter will take care of managing your dynamic view, you only need to take care of putting the correct data in the adapter.

Comment: The example you linked to was very helpful, but the last thing I've had trouble with it actually getting my custom DialogFragment to appear. What I mean is, what needs to be in the onClick of the button that makes my custom DialogFragment appear? As of now all I have is  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        DynamicDialogFrag alertDialog = (DynamicDialogFrag) DynamicDialogFrag.instantiate(this,"");
        alertDialog.show(fm, "tag"); 

and this isn't quite working.